# Cauchy-Type integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-principal-value

Greeting,
I have an integral to solve, it is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{g(x)}{x-z}dx$$
with $g(x)$ a smooth, continuous, positive function, and $z=z_r + iz_i$ a complex number.

I saw that this type of integral can be solved by using Cauchy principal part, to get
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{g(x)}{x-z}dx = P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{g(x)}{x-z_r}dx - i\pi g(z_r)$$
and $P\int$ is the principal part.

All is good, but how can I now solve the principal part? I know and have solved it by Taylor expanding the denominator. Is there a way to do it without Taylor expanding? If do how or can I have some references I can read?

Thank you for your time reading this.

edit: The function $g(x)$ i used to solve by Taylor expanding was a Gaussian
$$g(x)=e^{-x^2}$$

Comment: Do you know what form you’re hoping for in an answer? Without more information on $g(x)$, I’m not sure you can say anything more about the integral.

Comment: The function i'm using for testing is a Gaussian, however i can only do it by expanding the denominator. Thanks

Comment: The Cauchy principal value is relevant only when the integrand diverges at some point along the integration contour. That doesn’t seem to be your case, unless z_i = 0.

Comment: Yes, however i don't know a way of doing that type of integral other way. HumbleBEE wrote a good answer that looks like the things i found. So in short, i don't know

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're correctly using Cauchy's Principal Value. From what I can see from the notes of my Professor of Complex Analysis, given an integral for which Cauchy's Principal Value is needed, you have the following:
$$I = P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\ f(x) = 2\pi i \sum \text{Res}\big(f(z)\big) + i\pi \text{Res}_{z=x_0}\big(f(z)\big) - \lim_{R\to+\infty} \int_{\gamma}dz\ f(z)$$
where the integrand $f(x)$ has a simple pole in $x=x_0$. That is, $I$ can be expressed in terms of the residues of $f$, including the one at $x=x_0$. Moreover $\gamma$ is the half-circle in the complex plane centered at the origin with radius $R$. In order to make a useful formula of this statement we need to check if the limit of the last integral (the one along $\gamma$) tends to zero; in that case we'll be able to express $I$ only in terms of its residues. A sufficient condition is simply given by the following:
$$\lim_{|z|\to+\infty} |zf(z)| = 0 \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad \lim_{R\to+\infty} \int_{\gamma}dz\ f(z)$$

Now, in the case you proposed:
$$I = P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\ \dfrac{g(x)}{x-x_0} \qquad g(x)\in \mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$$
hence $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z-x_0}$ where $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$. Since:
$$\lim_{|z|\to+\infty} |zf(z)| = \lim_{|z|\to+\infty} \bigg|z\frac{g(z)}{z-x_0}\bigg| = \lim_{|z|\to+\infty} \bigg|\frac{z}{z-x_0}\bigg|\cdot\bigg|g(z)\bigg| = 0$$
Therefore we obtain:
$$I = P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\ \dfrac{g(x)}{x-x_0} = i\pi \text{Res}_{z=x_0}\big(f(z)\big) = i\pi g(x_0) = i\pi e^{-x_0^2}$$

In the case $x_0 = z_0\in\mathbb C$ you just simply compute the residues on the upper-half complex plane.

This is what I would say, though I checked on WolframaAlpha and I cannot understand its result. I hope this might be of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i looked at a course i had 2 years ago about this subject and i also found a physics book, by Richard Fitzpatrick,  treating a similar problem with a different function $g(z)$. I tried doing the calculations but get conflicting results but i don't know if i'm using the right method he doesn't develop the calculations. I will continue reading, if i found something i will post it here